# Issue with Firebase Realtime Database query

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm using firebase realtime database, i want to add a listener to check if new child is added or not.

My issue is i don't want to receive list of all children, that's why i'm query the db with startAt(TIMESTAMP), my nodes are named with timestamps as well, but i'm still receiving all the existing children at the start.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FIREBASE_URL).getReference();
    DatabaseReference parentRef = databaseReference.child(PARENT_NODE);
    dealRef = parentRef.child(CHILD_NODE);
    dealRef.orderByKey().startAt("1623418251");
    dealRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
```

[image: Firebase Db]

Comment: What does `String.valueOf(DateUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp())` return?

Comment: @AlexMamo it returns current timestamp in millis

Comment: i tried with hardcoding the key too

Comment: Please provide an example of your "current timestamp in millis".

Comment: @AlexMamo i have edited the code, i have hardcoded the node key, but still i'm receiving all the children

Comment: So when you are using `.startAt("1623418251")` you say you are also getting records that are before `1623418251`?

Comment: @AlexMamo OP has wrongfully assumed that `orderByKey()` and `startAt()` mutate `dealRef`.

Comment: I have edited code with `dealRef.orderByKey().startAt("1623418251").addChildEventListener(childEventListener);` and it's working now

Comment: Can anyone explain this, was this really an issue? @AlexMamo

Comment: @samthecodingman Good catch Sam ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at your code, we can see that you've created a instance of [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query), but you don't do anything with it. On the next line, you are expecting to be using this query, but you instead attach the listener to the raw `DatabaseReference`.

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FIREBASE_URL).getReference();
DatabaseReference parentRef = databaseReference.child(PARENT_NODE);
dealRef = parentRef.child(CHILD_NODE);

// this line creates a new `Query` object.
dealRef.orderByKey().startAt("1623418251"); 

// this line attaches childEventListener to dealRef, not the query from the previous line
dealRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

// onChildAdded -> will get fired for each child under dealRef, and any new children as they are added
```

To fix your current query, you should attach the child listener to the query:

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FIREBASE_URL).getReference();
DatabaseReference parentRef = databaseReference.child(PARENT_NODE);
dealRef = parentRef.child(CHILD_NODE);

Query dealQuery = dealRef
    .orderByKey()
    .startAt("1623418251");

dealQuery.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

// onChildAdded -> will get fired for the child "1623418251" and each child sorted after it, and any new children as they are added as long as they sort after "1623418251"
```

If your intention is to always get the newest child, and only the newest child, you can use:

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FIREBASE_URL).getReference();
DatabaseReference parentRef = databaseReference.child(PARENT_NODE);
DatabaseReference dealRef = parentRef.child(CHILD_NODE);

Query dealQuery = dealRef
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(1);

dealQuery.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

// onChildAdded -> gets fired with the newest child
// onChildRemoved -> gets fired with the previous newest child (after the first result)
```

Comment: `// .orderByKey() is the default, no need to add it here` It may seem that way, but the priority of a key may change matters. I *strongly* recommend always indicating an order, even if it may work without it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I thought priorities were deprecated so I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Priorities have been deprecated for many years by now indeed, but they still exist and can sometimes get in the way. Hence my request to always include an `orderBy...` call. 